# Get the full URL query string from document.location.href?

Tags: jquery, string, url

I need get the full URL

I need to cross from a domain parked on a landing page in the same base domain site.

I have a URL like this Example: landing page http://landing.name cross to base domain http://domain.name/test.html

I need define manually the full URL

My Code:

```
$('.add-it').click(function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        var uri = $(this).attr('href');

        $.get( uri, function( r ) {

            swal({
                title: "Test Title!",   
                text: r + "Test",   
                showCancelButton: true,   
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
                confirmButtonText: "Test",   
                cancelButtonText: "Test",   
                closeOnConfirm: true,   
                closeOnCancel: true, 
                html: true
            }, function(isConfirm) {   
                if (isConfirm) {     
                    document.location.href = '/test.html';
                } 
            });

        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            swal({ title: 'woops', text: error, type: "warning",  }); // or whatever
        });

        return false;

    });
```

the actual code work good but not with the full URL

I try to chenge

```
document.location.href = '/test.html';
```

to

```
location.href = 'http://domain.name/test.html';
window.location.href = 'http://domain.name/test.html';
```

But not work.

Please any help?
Many thanks in advances.

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to do, because setting `document.location.href` is working properly.

Comment: Hi Domenik, I need to cross from a domain parked on a landing page in the same base domain

I have a URL like this Example: landing page http://landing.name cross to base domain http://domain.name/test.html

Comment: Try `window.location.href = 'http://domain.name/test.html';` in the console with eg. google.com and it works.

Answer (score 0):

**In order to get current url you can use**

```
window.location.href
```

OR

```
document.URL;
```

To get hostname you can use `window.location.hostname`

So you can do like this way

// Sets the new location of the current window.

```
window.location = window.location.hostname+'/test.html';
```

// Sets the new href (URL) for the current window.

```
window.location.href = window.location.hostname+'/test.html';
```

Comment: Thanks bhunu but now work, I need cross from a domain parked on a landing page in the same base domain site,  I have a URL like this Example: landing page http://landing.name cross to base domain http://domain.name/test.html, I need define manually the full URL

Comment: you can get the domain name by using window.location.hostname

Comment: yes but get the domain name parked in the landing page http://landing.name/test.html but not the base domain :( for that reason I need made the full URL, thanks buddy